# How to define the following matrix?

Tags: matrix

How to define the following matrix?
[image]

Comment: Please provide any code that you've tried.

Comment: You could use [`ToeplitzMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToeplitzMatrix) for this, e.g., ``ToeplitzMatrix[{1,0,0,0},{1,a,b,c}]//MatrixForm``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's often easiest to construct matrices like this using `SparseArray` and `Normal`:

```
\[CapitalUpsilon][k_, a_] = (k + 1)^(a + 1) - 2 k^(a + 1) + (k - 1)^(a + 1);
mat[n_, a_] := 1/(n^a Gamma[a + 2]) Normal[
      SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1, 
      {i_, j_} /; j > i -> \[CapitalUpsilon][j - i, a]},
      {n, n}]]
```

In words, `SparseArray` creates an $n \times n$ matrix, sets all elements of the matrix of the form $M_{ii}$ to 1, and sets all elements of the form $M_{ij}$ for which $j>i$ equal to $\Upsilon_{j-i}$.

```
mat[5,2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. When I run your `SparseArray` code, I get the error `SparseArray::adims: Array dimension specification {n,n} should be Automatic, a non-negative machine integer, or a list of non-negative machine integers.` And When I run `mat[5,2] // MatrixForm`, I get `1/150`. First of all; If I define `n=3` etc., the code yields right results.

Comment: @rbrt_cpr:  Yes, this snippet only works for numerical values of `n`;  matrices in Mathematica have to have a definite size.  I'm not quite sure what the behavior you're describing might be due to.  It's possible that I had a stray variable in memory when I was defining things;  I will check on it again later today to confirm.

Comment: @rbrt_cpr:  Ah, I see the problem:  I put a line break in an unfortunate place in my code snippet.  To be clear, the factor `1/(n^a Gamma[a + 2])` should be multiplying `Normal[SparseArray[ .... ]]`  I think it will work better if you cut and paste it now.